# Android usb host permission confirmation dialog is being dismissed when I click outside of it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, usbserial

I am getting a android usb host permission confirmation dialog when I am establishing the USB connection from my android application.

```
PendingIntent mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        context.getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(
                                ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
                context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver,
                        filter);
                manager.requestPermission(driver.getDevice(), mPermissionIntent);
```

I want to implement that when the user clicks outside the dialog, the dialog will not be dismissed. What do I have to do for this? How to set `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);` for usb host permission confirmation dialog?

Comment: Hey bro start a bounty for this question..Its a very good question.

Comment: One option u have, that is u either want a OK or Cancel to be clicked by the user so that u can receive the option selected by the user through ur registered receivers. But 1 more info i would like to give is that, even if the user clicks outside the dialog box u will receive cancel being selected by user through ur same receiver. So the stuff ur trying to achieve will be possible

Comment: @DJphy  - Sorry for late response, I have tried all possible ways fro workaround but nothing work for me and yes app is receiving cancel broadcast in the same receiver. 
I put the patch for workaround as suggested by you. 
Thanks

Comment: Ah niice, welcome !

Answer (score 0):

The dialog hide trigger the same event of Cancel button. You can just check if the access is denied and study a logic to show again the authorization dialog or a custom dialog to inform the user that the app works just if he authorize USB access.